# 24 character limit for certain folders in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, filesystems

I am using Windows 10 Home edition. I have noticed in some of my folders there's a 24 character limit for the file names. I searched google and found that setting the value of LongPathsEnabled = 1 in RegEdit(Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\FileSystem) will fix this issue. However, the issue still exists. Can someone suggest me some windows tweaks to overcome this word limit?

For instance, if I created a file like balanced_vs_imbalanced_data.txt, it will come up with an error Rename. The file name you specified is not valid or too long. Specify a different file name.

Note that this issue is not there in every folder. But only in folders where I have copied the screenshots files from Microsoft OneDrive.

Comment: I never heard of a word limit, only character count. How did you determine this? It might help if you edit your question & add specific examples.

Comment: Keith Miller.. sorry I meant 24 character limit.

Comment: Is your Windows Home Edition 32-bit or 64-bit?

Comment: It is 64 bit Windows running on Intel i7.

Comment: did you restart your pc after making change in registry?

Comment: Yup...I did restart my PC.